# request in installing matConvNet in matlab?

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

I'm trying to install matconvent using matlab 2019  when i use  the command

untar('http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/download/matconvnet-1.0-beta25.tar.gz') ;
cd matconvnet-1.0-beta25 i have this error message

Error using untar (line 82)
Invalid Tar file
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tpb594175a_5490_4031_bd53_e06522210fb2.gz.

how i can solve this problem to install matConvNet

Comment: Did you try unpacking with some other software like 7zip?

Comment: no i didn't but  the issue is in the commande untar

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this, and it will run:

`untar ('matconvnet-1.0-beta25.tar.gz')`

Comment: hi, did you try the command you wrote in your answer? it seems like it doesn't work because the OP already did what you're suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the issue don't follow the instructions showing on the website that ask you to do like this

> > untar('http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/download/matconvnet-1.0-beta25.tar.gz') ;

BUT change the code line to be like this

> > untar('matconvnet-1.0-beta25.tar.gz')